# How to measure deltaTime in OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm measuring deltaTime like that:

```
deltaTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) / 1000.0f;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

screen.update(deltaTime);
screen.present(deltaTime);
```

But probably there are some accuracy problems.When use deltaTime for increasing my camera position's x,my screen starts to stutter.If i don't use deltaTime for that,there aren't any stuttering.So how can i use an efficient deltaTime measure system within OpenGL ES?

Comment: I've seen most examples use ``SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`` instead of ``System.currentTimeMillis()``. Can't tell for sure if it helped in your case though.

Comment: Are you having the `startTime` variable as a global member?

Comment: @Shelly Yes i have startTime as global variable.I have seen this article but i couldn't perform it with onDrawFrame.